# Как можно итерировать по str объекту с \n, \t

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, tab

Например, у меня есть переменная `html = '<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset ="utf-8">\n\t\t</meta>\n\t</head>\n<\html>'`
Как можно итерировать по каждой строке *html* без табуляций? Пробовал `for i in  html.strip().split():` не получается.
Без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: `strip` нужно применять к каждой строке. Т.е. сначала разбиваете на строки `for i in  html.split():`, потом внутри цикла например делаете `i = i.lstrip()`

Comment: Лучше с html работать специальными библиотеками вроде BeautifulSoup

Comment: @CrazyElf, знаю, просто хочу сам попробовать

Comment: @insolor, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала можно разбить на строки

```py
lines = html.splitlines()
```

`lines` будет содержать следующее

```py
['<html>', '\t<head>', '\t\t<meta charset ="utf-8">', '\t\t</meta>', '\t</head>', '<\\html>']
```

А затем можно итерироваться, убирая мешающие знаки:

```py
for i in lines:      
  print(i.replace('\t',''))
```

Вывод

```py
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
</meta>
</head>
<\html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, плохо знаю синтаксис и его применение (